# Docker port binding error

Tags: docker

I'm trying to bind my docker container to the specific ip and port. But I get the same error in any cases

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:885:4000 rubi/mknews   
FATA[0002] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container b790903695663bfeb5c24488b04283ae7:  (exit status 1)
```

Here is my ifconfig output

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ac4d:76ff:fe19:10c8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:608 (608.0 b)  TX bytes:180 (180.0 b)


lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:28448 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28448 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3778591 (3.6 MiB)  TX bytes:3778591 (3.6 MiB)
```

Comment: - what does `docker logs b790903695663bfeb5c24488b04283ae7` shows?
- what version of docker are you running? (type: `docker version`). 
- it might be that port 885 is already taken on your docker host. Type `netstat -ln | grep 885`

Comment: Fixed by reinstalling docker